# Sample Login in Php doesn't redirect

Tags: php, redirect, php-5.3

Hello I've followed a tutorial in php in creating a sample login system. but it doesn't seem to work. What's wrong with the code below.

login_success.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['myusername'])
{
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

It says that it "check if session is not registered , redirect back to main page." but whenever I put invalid username and password it doesn't go to the main_login.php but instead go to check_login.php

**UPDATE: 
The invalid username and password pops out on check_login.php I think it should be on main_login.php. I'll post the my entire code so that you can help me

check_login.php

```
    <?php

ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="root"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("Location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

main_login.php

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="check_login.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: Try `header("Location: main_login.php");`

Comment: sir where would I put that?

Comment: Set that dump session directly after the session start. That's fine.

Comment: @Daniel: "header("Location:main_login.php")" doesn't work sir. :(

Comment: I just put in a space. Try that. And see if you have that session variable set, like @zerkms suggests.

Comment: sir can you look at the entire code. why it is not working?

Comment: where is session getting set?

Comment: Sorry sir. I've updated my post

Answer (score 1):

May be the session is already set, when you try to login with correct credentials. You might have to unset the session variable during logout.

```
unset($_SESSION['myusername']);
```

Answer (score 1):

main_login.php // your page looks fine. The form action brings you to check_login.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="check_login.php">
```

check_login.php: // change session_register() to this:

```
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

$_SESSION["myusername"] = $myusername;
$_SESSION["mypassword"] = $mypassword;
```

login_success: // whole page in php tags

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['myusername'] = 'myname';

if (isset($_POST['myusername'])) {
    $user = $_POST['myusername'];
    if (!isset($_SESSION["myusername"]) || $user != $_SESSION['myusername']) {
        header("Location: main_login.php");
    }
}
else {
    echo "login successful";
}
```

I have tested this against a database and am positive this works fine.
You seem eager to learn, but you learn oldstyle php. Check out [phpacademy](https://www.phpacademy.org/) to learn newer stuff. Especially with the database you will be wise to learn PDO. Spend time on youtube and other resources.

Comment: I have corrected an error I made in the key names of the global variables. I started using "username" instead of "myusername". I apologize. I worked out this code snippet and it should work as expected.

Comment: Where would I put that code snippet sir? inside my main_login.html?

Answer (score 0):

Use "isset" to check if there's content in the session var. Something like

```
if(!(isset($_SESSION['myusername']))) {
       ...
}
```

Comment: Change "location" to "Location: main_login.php"

Comment: and what that session has? var_dump or print_r

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no PHP in the code above. it sounds like you would need to put some PHP in to check your session variable for you login token for instance you could have something like this.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername']){
        header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
        header("Location: http://localhost:8080/main_login.php");
    }

?>

<html>
    <body>
        Login Successful
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I see the issue now the post data from the main_login.php page does not look like it is used. You can try this for login_success.php

```
<?php
    $userName = $_POST['myusername'];
    $password = $_POST['mypassword'];

    /*Validate username and password - I am using a simple comparison because 
    I do not know if you are validating against a DB, text file, etx...*/

    if($userName == 'user' && $password == 'password'){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['myusername'] = $userName; //This is storing the validated username in session
    }else{
        header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
        header("Location: http://localhost:8080/main_login.php");
    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
        Login Successful
    </body>
</html>
```

Also [session_register was deprecated in PHP 5.3 and was removed from PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php)

Comment: Are you aware that the person is following a tutorial? .. I don't think these suggestions are helpful at this point.

Comment: @Daniel I apologize I somehow missed the top part of the question... I guess I will blame my poor internet connection :-)

Comment: @rjtubera Ok I have edited my answer based on the new info provided.

Comment: I'm validating against a DB sir.

Comment: it still redirect to check_login.php even if wrong username and pass

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm the mistake is in that you're trying to get a session value that you never have set, look at your form in the Html, it says "method = post", so, you need to catch the value in this way

```
if(isset($_POST['myusername'])){
...
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to set a value of a session you only have to write something like

```
$_SESSION['sessionName'] = value;
```

And, if you want to get the value of the session, just "call" it

```
echo $_SESSION['sessionName']; //echo is for output, not for calling
```

Remember that you aren't setting a value of a session, you are sending to the server values of the inputs, and you get those values with $_POST['nameOfInput'] or $_GET['nameOfInput']